# Counter example on continuity of blow-up time with respect to parameters

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, blowup

Consider the following differential equation (DE)
$$\dot{x}(t)=ax(t)+f(x(t))+u(t).$$
Let assume there is number $M$ such that the DE admits a local solution over some interval $[0,\tau]$ for all $|u(t)|\le M$.

Under this setting, can you find a counter examples in which the DE does not admit a solution over the same interval $[0,\tau]$ for $|u|>M$ or $u>M$ or $u<-M$?

Comment: My intuition is that $\tau$ should depend continuously on $\|u\|_\infty$.

Comment: Did you try the most simple settings $a=0$ and $f(x)=x^2$? Then you can apply methods for Riccati equations and find solvable examples for constant $u$.

Comment: Is one to assume that $x(0)=0$ (resp. $x(t)=0$ for $t<0$) or are there other restrictions or assumptions on the initial value?

Comment: No restriction on the initial condition.

Comment: Then any solution is infinitely extensible as long as $|u(t)|\le M$ for all times. You can force any behavior of $x$ by setting $u(t)=\dot p(t)-ap(t)-f(p(t))$ for any differentiable function $p:[0,τ)\to\Bbb R$. If $p$ has a pole at $t=τ$, the values of $u$ will leave eventually any bounded set.